# Sails-mysql refuses to register a connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, sails.js, waterline

I have my Sails application on an AWS instance with all dependancies installed with no apparent issues. However, each time I try to launch the app I am getting the following error.

```
error: AdapterError: Connection is already registered
```

I have not managed to successfully lift sails yet on the instance and sails-mysql was freshly installed so no connections should be registered.

I have taken the following steps to deploy my app..

- Set up a MySql RDS instance (EU-West)
- Created and set up an Ubuntu AMD-64 t2.micro EC2 instance (EU-West)
- Installed all prerequisites (Git, NVM, NodeJs, Sails, etc.)
- Cloned my Sails project
- Installed dependencies for Sails
- Correctly configured my connection settings for Sails to use my RDS instance.

I know that my connection settings are correct as I have been able to run Sails on my local machine with a connection to my RDS instance and it would consistently lift without any issues.

I am also able to connect to my RDS instance using SequelPro with no problems.

I have had issues with dependencies in the past but have managed to fix those issues and have not had any of them on my local machine or with my EC2 instance.

After searching for a while I have come across a few users who have had similar issues but have managed to fix them with Waterline's teardown methods, however, I am unsure how to achieve this.

I have done my best to provide as much information as possible and any help would be massively appreciated.

**Sails Version:** 0.12.11

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by carrying out the following:

- Switched my environment to production in `config/bootstrap.js`
- In `connections.js` add `connectTimeout: 20000` to make sure the request does not time out before the connection is made.

  eg. `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'`
- Ensure that the security group inbounds rules for the RDS allows connections from the security group associated with my EC2 instance.

**Type:** MySQL/Aurora

**Protocol:** TCP

**Port Range:** 3306

**Source:** < Your security group ID >

Following the above points also meant I overcame the issue with handshake timeouts when communicating with the RDS.